# How to calulate a cumulative sum for each observation by id

Tags: sas, ssas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

My problem is about calculating the cumulative sum for each id and for each date taking into account a sliding period of 15 previous days. If the cumulative sum exceeds 10k, the variable top is incremented.

The treatment is done for Juen only.

Here is an exemple of the desired result :

```
id  app_date    price   cum top 
1   29-juin-20  4000                 4 000  .
1   13-juin-20  5000               45 000   1
1   13-juin-20  6000               40 000   2
1   11-juin-20  7000               34 000   3
1   10-juin-20  8000               27 000   4
1   01-juin-20  9000               19 000   5
1   30-mai-20   10000              10 000   .

proc sort data = tab out= tab1;
by id descending app_date;

run;



data tab2;

set tab1;

%let annee=2020;

%let month=06;

by  id;

retain last_date date_last_d CUM;

if first.id then do;

      last_date =app_date;

      date_last_dem = app_date;

      CUM=0;

end;

if month(date_last_d) =&month. then do ;

diff= date_last_d -app_date;

CUM= price+ CUM;

end;

if diff>15 then do;

      diff = .;

      CUM =.;

      last_date =app_date;

      date_last_d = app_date;

end;

if last.id and CUM>10000 then top= top+1 ;

output;

last_date=app_date;

format last_date DDMMYY10.;

format date_last_d DDMMYY10.;

format CUM 14.2;



run;
```

I can do it for the first iteration but I cannot do it for all the lines.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
data have;
input Cnt Price ID App_date :ddmmyy10.;
format App_date ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
1  2265 534    30/05/2020
2  2330 4594   27/06/2020
3  1360 723    14/05/2020
4  1393 723    14/05/2020
5  2400 101666 12/06/2020
6  2411 101666 12/06/2020
7  2400 101666 11/06/2020
8  2400 101666 11/06/2020
9  2527 101666 10/06/2020
10 2536 101666 10/06/2020
11 2458 101666 04/06/2020
12 2758 1088   30/05/2020
13 4412 1056   13/06/2020
14 1870 1255   30/06/2020
15 4198 1255   14/05/2020
;

data want(drop = c k p dt);

   dcl hash h(ordered : "Y");
   h.definekey("c");
   h.definedata("c", "p", "dt");
   h.definedone();
   dcl hiter i("h");

   do c = 1 by 1 until (last.ID);
      set have(rename=(App_Date=dt Price=p));
      by ID notsorted;
      h.add();
   end;

   do k = 1 by 1 until (last.ID);
      set have;
      by ID notsorted;
      cum = 0;
      do while (i.next() = 0);
         if App_Date - 15 <= dt <= App_Date & k <= c then cum + p;
      end;
      if cum > 10000 then top + 1;
      else top = .;
      output;
   end;

   h.clear();
run;
```